# Proper way to pass an object to a function [python]

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a shooter game in python using pygame and have a question about the proper way to pass an object to a function.

Each player in the game will be assigned a certain team upon joining the game. There is a class called team which keeps track of the status of a team (Score, number of players, etc.). The team objects are stored in a list. Sometimes, a function will need to look at and/or modify a team object. I'd like to know which of the following two methods is a better way to pass the team object to a function.

**Method 1:**

Each team object has a attribute which is an integer called teamId. Each teamId is unique. If another function needs to access the team object, it will be passed the teamId, search through the list of teams until it finds the object with the appropriate teamId and then use that object.

Example:

```
def functionThatNeedsTeam(teamId):
    team = getTeamById(teamId)
    doSomething()
    return

functionThatNeedsTeam(teamId)
```

**Method 2:**

If a function needs to access a team object, it will be passed the team object itself.

Example:

```
def functionThatNeedsTeam(team):
    doSomething()
    return

functionThatNeedsTeam(teamObject)
```

I've seen both of these methods used in various pygame projects that I've looked at and would like to know which one is better. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would prefer the second option : passing the object, as it avoids looking up in a list of objects.

Comment: Method 1 is massively ugly. Just pass the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the function what data it needs to do its job.

Does it have a use for the ID? Then you should pass that as a parameter. Otherwise, pass the team, or if it only uses one attribute of the team, consider passing that instead.

Most of the time doing what leads to less code is correct.